# Adding a number to an array variable in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

In the [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/inner_product/) page for the inner_product module they gave a code example:

```
int init = 100;
int series1[] = {10,20,30};
int series2[] = {1,2,3};
std::cout << "using default inner_product: ";
std::cout << std::inner_product(series1,series1+3,series2,init);
std::cout << '\n';
```

Where I saw them use `series1+3` when calling the inner_product funtcion.

What exactly does adding "3" to the array variable do?

Comment: _"What exactly does adding "3" to the array variable do?"_ Pointer arithmetics.

Comment: Seems like a legitimate question, since series1 is not a pointer.  In this case there is an implicit conversion to a pointer type.

Comment: @stark Arguable. Not great of research efforts shown here.

Comment: Helpful reading: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying).

Comment: A hadn't heard of the term "pointer adition" yet. I'm assuming that series1 on itself is a pointer to the first element of the array...

Comment: If you haven't heard "pointer addition" yet then you definitely need to keep studying your C++ book :)

Comment: Try "pointer arithmetic" instead. In your address bar if the book doesn't have anything.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I forgot it's an Ebook you're right. I can't. Hard to do research on some ambiguous term you've never heard of that's not in you're study material though...

Comment: @nwp yup did that that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What exactly does adding "3" to the array variable do?

The array operand decays into a pointer to first element of the array. 3 is added to that pointer, so that the result is a pointer to 3 elements after the first (i.e. the element at index 3), which is immediately outside the bounds of the array. The addition is equivalent to `std::end(series1)` which would be more idiomatic in my opinion.

> I'm assuming that series1 on itself is a pointer to the first element of the array

You assume wrong. `series1` is not a pointer, but an array. However, an id-expression (standardese for the name of the variable) of an array will decay into a pointer in value contexts.